# Issue with splitting string in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I cant seem to split this string, I would like to get the last 8 numbers as 'Date' in the format of YYYY-MM-DD. I would like to use the _filename to feed through and generate the date.

select

split(split("gs://mmmm_ssss_count_detail/mmm_ssss_count_detail_20220125.csv",'/')[offset(2)],'_')[offset(3)]

This just gives me 'detail' which is not what I need, it should at least give me '20220125.csv' where I can then remove the .csv part and parsedate it to 'Date' in my main select query.

Help please.

Comment: Is there a way to use a double split on this to eliminate the '/' and then the '_' and be left with just "20220125.csv", where i can remove the ".csv" and parsedate what is left?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a split, can you use a regex to find the date value?  If so try the following:

```
select 
    parse_date("%Y%m%d",regexp_extract(path, r'_(\d+)\.csv'))
from sample_data
```

The regex string above is looking for a pattern where a set of digits `(\d+)` exists between an `_` and `.csv`

With the sample string you provided it yields:

[image]

Comment: Terrific! If it helped please consider uprooting and making the answer correct

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach / option

```
select _filename, 
  parse_date('%Y%m%d', array_reverse(split(replace(_filename, '.', '_'), '_'))[offset(1)]) file_date
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]